# How to prevent access to chrome's task manager

Tags: google-chrome, task-manager

Hi so in order to prevent extensions from being killed I'm trying to figure out how to prevent access to chrome's task manager. **I am well aware people have asked this before on superuser**, **but there aren't any solutions given**. Also yes I am aware I could just delete my google profile and then have no extensions, but do not worry about that I am just concerned about disabling the task manager.

Are there any solutions / suggestions on what should I do? Thank you for your time.

Please be aware I'm on a Mac Book Air on High Sierra.

Comment: You can't. On any OS the root or admin user always has access to any part of the system.

Comment: _"I am well aware people have asked this before on superuser, but there aren't any solutions given"_ Sorry, that's no excuse to post a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

There is a regex setting called TaskManagerEndProcessEnabled that if set to zero will disable ability to end tasks from task manager.

https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#TaskManagerEndProcessEnabled

Answer (score 0):

To block Task Manager:
In the Google Admin console, go to Device Management > Chrome Management > User settings > Apps and Extensions.
From the left panel, select the organization.
Under Task Manager select Block users from ending processes with the Chrome Task Manager from the drop-down list.
Click Save.